# Get current GIT tag from within Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get the most recent GIT tag from within a Rails app? The tag is my release version and I'd like to show in my app.

I know that this will give me the most recent commit:

`git rev-parse --short HEAD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tag = `git describe`.chomp
```

> The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit.
>   If the tag points to the commit, then only the tag is shown.
>   Otherwise, it suffixes the tag name with the number of additional
>   commits on top of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of
>   the most recent commit. The result is a "human-readable" object name
>   which can also be used to identify the commit to other git commands.
>
> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe

You can suppress the suffix with:

```
tag = `git describe --abbrev=0`.chomp
```

Comment: You might want to check `$?.exitstatus == 0` to make sure the command was successful through before outputting it.